# Fill table based on stored procedure with uncertain ordered columns

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, temp-tables

I try to insert the outcome of a stored procedure into a table in SQL Server. It's part of something dynamic so what I do now is something like this:

```sql
SET @SQL = 'INSERT INTO [' + @DestinationTable + '](' + @fieldlist_target + ') EXEC ' + @SP
```

But the problem now is that `@DestionationTable` can be this structure:

```
ColumnA int  
ColumnB varchar(255)  
ColumnC datetime
```

And the stored procedure can (accidentally) output these 3 columns in a different order (by example start with `ColumnC`).

I've tried many things like inserting `EXEC ' + @SP` into a temp table or using it in a subquery so that I can do:

```sql
SET @SQL = 'INSERT INTO ['+@DestinationTable+']('+@fieldlist_target+') SELECT '+@fieldlist_target+' FROM #TableThatICanCreate
```

But this all doesn't work because of the fact that I have to define the temp table as well. And there is nothing that I can do to have the columns in the right order.

I've tried by example this:

```sql
DECLARE @fieldlist_datatype_target varchar(max) = (SELECT STRING_AGG(CONCAT([name], ' ', [system_type_name]), ', ') AS Name_DataType
    FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(CONCAT('EXEC ', @SP), null, 0))
```

This works as it should and fixes mainly my issue because `@fieldlist_datatype_target` then is filled with all the stored procedure output in the correct order. BUT this doesn't work for more exotic stored procedures like the one that use temp tables. Then `sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set` returns:

> The metadata could not be determined because statement ... in procedure 'usp_...' uses a temp table.

So the question is: how to deal with this issue? I can't imagine I'm the only one but my whole search ends in 2 ways of doing this:

1. Predefine temp table (which I now can't because of that `sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set` is not working always)
2. Using `OPENROWSET` which I don't want to

Comment: *"And the SP can (accidently) output these 3 columns in a different order (by example start with ColumnC)."* Sounds like the problem is the procedure, not the `INSERT` statement. Fix the procedure and make the order of the columns deterministic.

Comment: Sounds like you need to enforce the order of the column names in which ever query collects them, in the original sproc.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. even hacks like openquery use sys.sp_describe_first_result_set and friends to resolve the metadata. if you know the number of columns, you could perhaps create the temp table with sql_variants, which at least would allow you to resolve the datatype. But it's still bad

Comment: For me it's very very very hard to believe that SQL can process millions of rows in seconds, that with AI we can generate images, movies and all other stuff but that there is no way to match the output of an SP (ColumnC, ColumnA, ColumnB) to a table with the same columnnames but different ordering.

Data Factory can do this by example in the mapping tab, but I want to create something generic which inserts the outcome op usp_NAME to dbo.NAME. And sometimes the table has many columns and I just want to concert the contents and not the ordering.

Is this really not achievable at all?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert results of a stored procedure into a temporary table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/insert-results-of-a-stored-procedure-into-a-temporary-table)

Comment: It's because SQL Server is very particular about table metadata that this becomes hard. You can read through the answers in the duplicate link  to see that OPENROWSET seems to be the only way.

Comment: Seems an odd design to return the columns in a different order...